# Retrieving Longitude and Latitude fron address passed to server

Tags: java, android, location

I pose an interesting question. What I'm trying to achieve is I have a list of merchants and their address. I want their longitude and latitude so I can determine if the user (using location listener) is within a one kilometre radius of that merchant. I have done  the code to determine if they are within that radius.

What I need is the merchants longitude and latitude as I said. Is there a soap service that I can use to pass the address of the merchant and it responds with the longitude and latitude? Or can I send that to google places API somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question under Android, I'm going to take a hit and assume that by "how do I use this with java", you actually mean how can I do this on the android platform.

Luckily, android provides the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) APIs that you can use for geocoding addresses into lon/lat co-ordinates, by doing the following :

```
gc = new Geocoder(this); //create new geocoder instance
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String addressInput = adress.getText().toString(); //Get input text 
    try {
      List<Address> foundAdresses = gc.getFromLocationName(addressInput, 5); //Search addresses
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      //@todo: Show error message
    }
  }
});
```

([above quoted from AndDev tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/simple_googlemaps_geocoder_-_convert_address_to_lon-lat-t2936.html))

Once you've got the lon/lats, you can create a [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) and slap them on a map, [link here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/converting-uk-postcodes-to-co-ordinates-to-use-in-android/) on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Google Maps API does what you need via their GEOCODING support.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Geocoding

Comment: How could I use this with java?

Comment: They have a service that you could call via an HttpRequest, getting back JSON or XML as a response - you'd presumably be able to extract lat + long from this response?

Comment: Yes that can be achieved. I will just have to learn how to send the http request and extract, but I've done that before so I should be ok. Thankyou.